# Django, Apache, WSGIDaemonProcess, and threads

Tags: python, django, apache, gil

I'm trying to tune the performance of a Django app that's served through Apache.

When doing load testing with Locust, I'm finding that latency is very high when the server is under heavy load. Right now I'm using the `mpm_event_module` using `ThreadsPerChild=25` since that seems to be a common thing I've found in example configs. Similarly, inside my site config I have

`WSGIDaemonProcess ... processes=8 threads=15 python-path=...`

since this also matched some example.

I was wondering whether the GIL in Python applies to the webserving when configured this way. If so, does that mean I need to change my config to use more processes and fewer threads to get more parallelism? When I tried doing this, my load testing reported many more failures when loading static files, so I'm not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: The GIL applies to all Python code (not linked binary code) executed by a CPython runtime.  wrt/ statics - assuming you're NOT using Django to serve them of course (else you're doing it wrong - and it's documented), if they are served by the same Apache instance, that's indeed some additionnal load on the server. That's why, for high performances, it's better to separate static / media files from application (distinct servers on distinct nodes, each optimized for it's own job).

Comment: Oh and yes: you're not running the load test process on the same node, are you ?-)

Comment: I wasn't asking about statics in particular I was asking whether I should change my config to do something like `ServerLImit 10, ThreadsPerChild 5` instead of `ServerLimit 2, ThreadsPerChild 25`, for example.

Comment: I've never used mpm_event, and we've switched to nginx/gunicorn long ago (for performance reasons, surprise surprise) so I don't have a serious answer to your question - else I would have posted it xD. I was just addressing the "whether the GIL in Python applies" part and pointing a couple potential issues with either your server setup or test setup (which you are probably already aware of, but I thought they might be worth mentionning just in case).